# Parallel Insertion in To Cassandra(using multiple threads) while paralley reading from Oracle DB

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, cassandra

I am trying to insert close to 30 million rows from oracle into cassandra.

Here is little snippet of code,which I put together quickly.
I am getting **java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset** and in case I make my dbread smaller
(that is fetching just 500000 records) it only inserts close to 3500000 or lower,it is forcing me to run cassandra insertion in single thread which is taking close to 2.5 hrs for 30 millions)

Here is code :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.pega.dbutils.DataBaseUtils;

import cassandraconnect.learncassandra.ConnectionToDB;

public class DumpMultiThreadedDumpInCassandra {

    Connection connection = null;
    Cluster cluster = null;
    Session session = null;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DumpMultiThreadedDumpInCassandra dumpInCassandra = new DumpMultiThreadedDumpInCassandra();
        dumpInCassandra.openConnectionWithCassadnra();
        try {
            dumpInCassandra.getDataFromDbInToMemoryAndInsertInCassandra();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            System.out.println("Closing the cassandra cluster");
            dumpInCassandra.session.close();
            dumpInCassandra.cluster.close();
            dumpInCassandra.connection.close();
        }

    }

    private void openConnectionWithCassadnra() {

        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(ipaddress).build();
        session = cluster.connect("data");
        System.out.println(session.getCluster().getClusterName());

    }

    private void getDataFromDbInToMemoryAndInsertInCassandra() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {`enter code here`
        String insertSQL = "insert into table(pysubjectid,pyissue,pygroup,pyname,pxoutcometime,price,sequence) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        final com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = session.prepare(insertSQL);

        int threads = 3;

        connection = ConnectionToDB.openConnection();

        String Query = "select SUBJECTID,ISSUE,GROUPISSUE,NAMEPROP,OUTCOMETIME,PRICE,factidint from oracletable where factidint>="+startrange +" "+"and"+" "+ "factidint<="+endstartrange;
        //String Query = "select SUBJECTID,ISSUE,GROUPISSUE,NAMEPROP,OUTCOMETIME,PRICE,factidint from oracletable ";
        System.out.println("Query is"+">>>"+Query);

        java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        final BlockingQueue<IHFactRecords> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<IHFactRecords>();

        final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(Query);

            long countprocessed=0;
          while (resultSet.next()) { blockingQueue.offer(new
         IHFactRecords(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2),
         resultSet.getString(3), resultSet.getString(4),
         Timestamp.valueOf(resultSet.getString(5)), resultSet.getLong(6),
          resultSet.getLong(7)));
          countprocessed++;
          if(countprocessed%1000000==0){
              System.out.println("million put in memory");


          }


          }
        DataBaseUtils.close(resultSet);
        DataBaseUtils.close(statement);

        /*ExecutorService readThreadservice = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        readThreadservice.submit(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (resultSet!= null){
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        blockingQueue.offer(new IHFactRecords(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2),
                                resultSet.getString(3), resultSet.getString(4),
                                Timestamp.valueOf(resultSet.getString(5)), resultSet.getLong(6), resultSet.getLong(7)));

                    }}
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });*/

        System.out.println("Sleeping for 5 seconds");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out
                .println("size of blocking queue populated in separated thread is now simultaneously starting ingestion"
                        + ">>>" + blockingQueue.size());
        long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
        final AtomicInteger totalcountinserted = new AtomicInteger(0);
        System.out.println("starting threads for parallel ingestion");
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    IHFactRecords ihrecord;
                    while ((ihrecord = blockingQueue.poll()) != null) {
                        BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind();

                        boundStatement.setString(0, ihrecord.getSubjectID());
                        boundStatement.setString(1, ihrecord.getIssue());
                        boundStatement.setString(2, ihrecord.getGroup());

                        boundStatement.setString(3, ihrecord.getPropsition());

                        boundStatement.setTimestamp(4, ihrecord.getTime());
                        boundStatement.setVarint(5, BigInteger.valueOf(ihrecord.getPrice()));
                        boundStatement.setVarint(6, BigInteger.valueOf(ihrecord.getSequence()));

                        session.execute(boundStatement);

                        int createdtillnow = totalcountinserted.incrementAndGet();
                        if (createdtillnow % 100000 == 0)
                            System.out.println("Total records inserted till now are" + ">>" + createdtillnow);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        executorService.shutdown();

        executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        //readThreadservice.shutdown();
        //readThreadservice.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("time in seconds" + ">>>" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endTime - starttime));
        System.out.println("time in minutes" + ">>>" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(endTime - starttime));
        System.out.println("time in hrs" + ">>>" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(endTime - starttime));
        ;
        DataBaseUtils.close(resultSet);
        DataBaseUtils.close(statement);

    }

}
```